# Why doesn't VS Code Cpptools' GCC problem matcher match against linker errors, and how can I make it so?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Most errors are reported normally, but some errors are not:

e.g. undefined reference to `Next(int*, std::string&)'

The declear of "Next" is missing a "const".

```cpp
void Next(int next[], string &t); 
...
void Next(int next[], const string &T)
{
    next[0] = 0;
    next[1] = 0;
    int plen = T.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < plen; ++i)
    {
        int j = next[i];
        while (j && T[i] != T[j])
            j = next[j];
        if (T[i] == T[j])
            next[i + 1] = j + 1;
        else
            next[i + 1] = 0;
    }
}
...
```

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO20h.jpg)
[problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzdHN.jpg)

and here my VS Code JSON files:

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file", 
            "command": "C:/environments/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/environments/mingw64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
 
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/environments/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable neat printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set disassembly style to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

I've tried other ides such as VS or Devc++.They can show the problem normally.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add some example linker errors in a code block instead of the screenshot? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's just unsupported in the current implementation of the GCC problem matcher to match against linker errors. See [Add detection of linker errors to gcc problem matcher #10383](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10383), which is currently closed as "more votes needed". You can contribute to its reopening by giving it a thumbs-up reaction.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode-cpptools issues linker error problem`".

In the meantime, you can augment the gcc problem matcher by adding one of your own to the `problemMatcher` array field. For instructions on how to do so, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher. If you want some inspiration, you can take a look at [this similar issue ticket where someone augmented `$msCompile`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4957#issuecomment-590412155).